# How to show Title from text file on Browsers Tab instead of on page Haskell, HTML

Tags: html, haskell, formatting

I have the standard format for HTML. I have written a program that takes an input.txt file and outputs an HTML file modified to be in HTML format. However, now I need to take the first line of the input file and output it in the title tag, so "Title Goes Here" is seen on the browser tab instead of the browsers page. Any ideas how I could make this happen?? head and tail?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
          <head>
          <title>Title Goes Here</title>
          </head>

          <body>
          body goes here
          </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What have you written so far?

Comment: the program is complete, it reads a text file, performs transformations on lines and words, and outputs an HTML file. I didnt want to put all the code up here, but it's basically just a bunch of functions. I just don't know where to start on getting the head and tail to go into this format. I've got similar code that outputs h1 h2 strong em tags on certain lines of the file.

Comment: You mean you're trying to work out how to separate the first line of text from the rest of the input?

Comment: Well I know that after I have broken up the entire file which was read as 1 String, into lines, using the function line, all I have to do is take the head of the String, which would be the first line (the title) and then everything but the head, so the tail (for the body) I just dont know how to implement these two methods to get it to print within this HTML format.

Comment: Is this entire HTML code going to be a part of my project? If so, how? or do I just need to throw head x in between the title tags, and tail x in between the body tags. Or do I need to write a new function, maybe like a format function that will do this?